# React native - navigation custom transition

Tags: navigation, react-native, transition

I would like to know if some of you did some navigation custom transition in React native. I know about few possibilities which react offers but they are not suitable for my purposes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to customise.

Check this example

```
'use strict';
var React = require('React');
var ReactNative = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = ReactNative;

var SCREEN_WIDTH = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
var BaseConfig = Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;

var CustomLeftToRightGesture = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig.gestures.pop, {
  // Make it snap back really quickly after canceling pop
  snapVelocity: 8,
  // Make it so we can drag anywhere on the screen
  edgeHitWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH,
});

var CustomSceneConfig = Object.assign({}, BaseConfig, {
  // A very tighly wound spring will make this transition fast
  springTension: 100,
  springFriction: 1,
  // Use our custom gesture defined above
  gestures: {
    pop: CustomLeftToRightGesture,
  }
});

var PageOne = React.createClass({
  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({id: 2,});
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'green'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Greetings!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go to page two</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
  },
});

var PageTwo = React.createClass({
  _handlePress() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: 'purple'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>This is page two!</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePress}>
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>Go back</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    )
  },
});

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.id === 1) {
      return <PageOne navigator={navigator} />
    } else if (route.id === 2) {
      return <PageTwo navigator={navigator} />
    }
  },

  _configureScene(route) {
    return CustomSceneConfig;
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id: 1, }}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        configureScene={this._configureScene} />
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: 'white',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Source: https://rnplay.org/apps/HPy6UA

Comment: This example is great, but I still would like to know if I can do something like this. After clicking the blue area it should expand to fullscreen smoothly as you can see on this picture I illustrated down below <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/s213fkyph/Galaxy_S5_Mockup_flat.jpg" width="400" height="400">

Comment: Should be possible. You need to play around with sceneConfigs https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/f64538943e180adc2180d89285fab6727eaf3982/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorSceneConfigs.js

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will need to figure out this part :)